# rewrite URL's with blank variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite the following URL's in htaccess?

```
1. domain.com/search.php?c=category&search=searchword&var3=variable&page=pagenumber
2. domain.com/search.php?c=category&search=searchword&var3=variable
3. domain.com/search.php?c=category&search=&var3=variable&page=pagenumber
4. domain.com/search.php?c=category&search=&var3=variable
```

I want the URL's to look as:

```
1. domain.com/search/category/searchword/variable/pagenumber
2. domain.com/search/category/searchword/variable
3. domain.com/search/category/variable/pagenumber
4. domain.com/search/category/variable
```

I have URL's 1 and 2 working in htaccess, but I need 3 and 4 working with a blank search variable.

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&search=$2&var3=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&search=$2&var3=$3[L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unless you cam discern searchword from variable, there's no way to concretize the rules/placeholders. This is not a case that calls for pretty urls anyway.

Comment: if I check for empty($search) I can run if else statements, but is it possible to rewrite the URL's in htaccess?